# Web application accessible with alternate url

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server

I have a web application with url: http://hydsp:2020. I would like to change the url to **http://hydsp:2020/sites/myhome**

The web application should accessible with only second url but not first. I am using SharePoint 2013 on premises.

Please suggest me the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- [Backup](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607901.aspx) your site collection from `http://hydsp:2020`.

> ```
> Backup-SPSite http://hydsp:2020 -Path C:\Backup\site_name.bak
> ```

- Create a new site `myhome` at the same web application to be under `sites`
- [Restore](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607788.aspx) it to `myhome` site site

> ```
> Restore-SPSite http://hydsp:2020/sites/myhome -Path C:\Backup\site_name.bak
> ```

To let only the site accessible from only the new URL,

- you can't stop this web application because of your subsite `myhome` at the same web application.
- So you can add redirect web part if someone tries to access the old URL go directly to the new URL

  - At the home page of  `http://hydsp:2020/` add Script editor to redirect directly to `http://hydsp:2020/sites/myhome`

> ```
> <script>
> $(document).ready(function() {
> window.location.href = "http://hydsp:2020/sites/myhome"; //redirect
> }
> </script>
> ```

**Note** : Don't Remove-SPSite at `http://hydsp:2020` because it's the site collection that will hold your subsite `http://hydsp:2020/sites/myhome`

See also

- [How to move a site collection from one web application to another (Or change it’s port)](https://blog.devoworx.net/2012/10/28/how-to-move-site-collection-from-one-webapplication/)
- [page-redirect-in-sharepoint-using-javascript](https://blog.devoworx.net/2016/01/16/page-redirect-in-sharepoint-using-javascript/)